# can't get to grub (even with right key). (recovering journal)

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04

I'm on a single boot. I can't get to the grub and if I can I can't move using the arrow keys. I'm Kinda confused on how I got to the grub in the first place. I have used 2 diffrent keyboards one wireless one wired.(sometimes I can get in with just turning it on).  plz help (recovering journal issue)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) And provide us more detail.

Comment: I had this problem in Ubuntu 22.04 following a kernel update immediately after which I rebooted. I solved this problem by uninstalling the latest kernel version.

Comment: If one install, grub menu is not normally shown. With UEFI you press escape just after UEFI screen & before grub menu would normally appear. Is old BIOS you press & hold shift key. But if you have fast boot on in UEFI settings, that assumes no system change and immediately boots without system scan. Then you have no time to press  a key. You then may be able to "cold" boot or full power down, drain all power & boot, so it does a system scan & gives you time to press correct key to get into UEFI settings, or grub menu.